# Based on these HTTPS requests what type of attack is this?

Tags: attacks, api, web-service, incident-analysis

I'm seeing over 1000 attempts to hit my API endpoints with many 500 responses. It seems clear that the would-be attacker is attempting to poke around the APIs, but it isn't clear to me what type of attack they're attempting. Hoping someone here can identify this.

Many of the requests include a random string in a handful of locations, e.g. `zcexystba7`:

- The `Origin` header is set to `https://zcexystba7.com`
- The user agent is set to `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0 zcexystba7`
- The `Accept` header includes `text/zcexystba7`
- The `Accept-Encoding` header includes `zcexystba7`
- A GET request URL parameter includes `zcexystba7=1`

Sometimes only a subset of these exist with the random string. The string varies in length, e.g. `yg6x1` is another example. Almost all of the requests include the random GET request parameter.

My first thought was maybe a BREACH attack, but the random string used in each request doesn't look like anything secret to me. I don't think that's it.

The timing of the requests indicates that the attacker is using a tool/script (e.g. 20 requests in 1.5 seconds).

Any ideas what the attacker may be attempting to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know just by looking at the requests exactly what the attacker is attempting. However, the most likely scenario is that the attacker is simply fuzzing your API and looking for any anomalous responses that would warrant manual review by the attacker.

Comment: What surprises me is that none of the requests contain special characters or non-ascii encodings. They're all similarly ascii with lowercase alphanumerics. It doesn't seem like they're trying to guess request parameter names (you'd try dictionary, not random characters, right?). Even if fuzzing it seems like they're doing a bad job at it. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @theoneandonly2 It most likely checks if one of these strings is reflected in the response.

Comment: Ah, agreed. That does seem like the most likely situation. Feel free to answer and I'll accept